# Block Select List Data from Google Bot

Tags: php, html, seo

When Google's Spiders are crawling one of my sites, they are pulling the data from select lists as page data. I completely understand why this is happening, but the question is, can it be blocked in any way? I don't want to block the entire page from being crawled, but merely the select list data.

The problem is as follows: When searching Google, the select list data is being shown as the summary of the page, instead of the  content. The description tag is specifically written to help SEO and to provide useful information to potential site visitors, but its intended function isn't being implemented.

Check this sample case [https://www.google.com/search?q=alaskan klee kai site%3Awiki-pet.com](https://www.google.com/search?q=alaskan%20klee%20kai%20site%3awiki-pet.com)

This is hurting the effectiveness of search performance on the site because more than 1 page is showing identical data in the search results. There are over 200 pages with the exact same select list allowing for easy navigation. The select lists will not be removed.

One idea i had was to fill the contents with an onload() script after the page has

completely loaded.. any ideas?

[**EDIT**]

Look at search result #3 & 5 containing this text: "All Breeds - - -, Affenpinscher, Afghan Hound, Airedale Terrier, Akbash Dog, Akita, Alapaha Blue Blood Bulldog, Alaskan Klee Kai, Alaskan ..."

This is content directly from the select lists on the associated pages.

Comment: I've found 2 possible solutions, both of which look sketchy at best. 1) The addition of Yahoo's class=”robots-nocontent” 2) Google has a <!-- google_ad_section_start(weight=ignore) --> tag used for advertisements that may work..

Comment: For anyone coming across this in the future, i'd suggest loading items that you don't want crawled by the spiders using JS after page load complete (a type of "lazy load").

Answer (score 0):

On the server, check whether the user agent matches `Googlebot` (or other popular spiders, such as `bingbot`) and don't render that content.

Comment: As far as i know, you can't exclude certain DIVs of content from a bot. Exclusion of an entire page is easily possible through robots.txt, but that is undesirable.

Comment: @BizLab: Yes, you can.  Just check the `User-Agent` header in an `if`.